# How can I reference a local copy of an SVG namespace?

Tags: c#, html, svg, namespaces

I'm running a program that reads an SVG file, but my internet has been intermittent lately and I'd like to reference a local copy of the svg namespace. I've downloaded the html archive for http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/ but it contains tons of html files, and I don't know which one I should reference in my code. When my internet is fully functional, this C# code works:

```
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any copy at all. The URI `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg` is used solely as an identifier; if two elements have namespace URIs that are character-for-character identical, then they have the same namespace name, otherwise they do not. There is no need for anything to be downloaded, and this should not even be attempted in most cases. A valid namespace URI need not even respond to GET requests.

Comment: Ok, but then why does it fail when I'm not connected to the internet? Thanks for your response.